# passing Date from onClick listener to another class

Tags: android

From a selected value, I want to send it to another variable

```
        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                year = selectedyear;
                month = selectedmonth;
                day = selectedday;
                stardate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" "));
            }
        }, year, month, day);
        mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
        mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mDatePicker.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can pass values to another class by methods, instance variables, `Serializable`s. What is your issue exactly?

Comment: Do you want to pass the value to another activity from "onDateSet" method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, replace the above code with this

```
DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
            year = selectedyear;
            month = selectedmonth;
            day = selectedday;
            String date = "" + day + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year;
            stardate.setText(date);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("date",date);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().

    setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mDatePicker.show();
}
});
```

In NewActivity.java to retrieve the data

in onCreate() method :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) {
            String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
        }
```

Comment: It's Showing me error                                                                       Requireed:
java.lang.String
Found:
java.lang.StringBuilder  on String date = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ");

Comment: thanks for ur correction. Can u tell me how to get that value as i am a beginer in this

Comment: Added that piece of code as weell. check it now nik! :)

Comment: thak u.will u give me one favor i have taken date value in my required format in a string variable and i want to use it in the same code for finding date diffrence how can i do it

Comment: Show me your piece of code where you have used in converting into your required format.

Comment: Upvote and Mark this as answer If this helped you in resolving the exact issue that you questioned in the subject.

Comment: String YY = Integer.toString(year);
                        String MM = String.format("%02d", month + 1);
                        String DD = String.format("%02d", day);
                        String selecteddate = YY;
                        selecteddate = selecteddate.concat(MM);
                        final String selecteddate1 = selecteddate.concat(DD);I WANT TO USE THIS SELECTEDDATE1 AS my from date in finding the date difference canu plz heip me in this

Comment: @nik the question you asked now is completely different than to the subject, so I request you to raise a new question and mention the link here and I will try to resolve it.  Also upvote this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564515/passing-string-values-to-other-function-from-onclick-date-listner

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Intent I=new Intent(context,your next activity.class);
I.putExtra("day",day);
I.putExtra("month",month);
I.putExtra("year",year);
startActivity(I);
```

Or

You can use

```
Intent I=new Intent(context, yourNextActivity.class);
I.putExtra("date",your StringBuilder object);
```

Comment: thanks for ur comment .But i want to use it in same activity. and want to use that date how can i . plz help i am new to this

Comment: i just want to user take the date from calander and i want to use it for finding the date diffrence with current date

Answer (score 0):

Decleare a public variable and store the value of date in string format in use it in your code anywhere no need to use intent or object.