# passing string values to other function from onclick date listner

Tags: java, android, string, date

I need a date in the format like "yyyyMMDD" so i converted my date in my required format as

```
String YY = Integer.toString(year); 
String MM = String.format("%02d", month + 1); 
String DD = String.format("%02d", day); 
String selecteddate = YY; 
selecteddate = selecteddate.concat(MM); 
final String selecteddate1 = selecteddate.concat(DD);
```

I want to use `selecteddata1` AS my from date in finding the date difference.

Comment: " I want to use selecteddata1 AS my from date in finding the date difference. " please explain clearly so that we can help you :)

Comment: i am unable to pass data in selecteddate1 string for finding date difference in another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nik,

Try this

```
DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
            year = selectedyear;
            month = selectedmonth;
            day = selectedday;
            String date = "" + day + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year;
            stardate.setText(date);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");

      try {

        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(""+day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year");
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/10/2013"); //If you want to use the current date, use "new Date()"

    printDifference(date1, date2);

      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().

    setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mDatePicker.show();
}
});

//1 minute = 60 seconds
    //1 hour = 60 x 60 = 3600
    //1 day = 3600 x 24 = 86400
    public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

        //milliseconds
        long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

        System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
        System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
        System.out.println("different : " + different);

        long secondsInMilli = 1000;
        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
        long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

        long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
        different = different % daysInMilli;

        long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
        different = different % hoursInMilli;

        long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
        different = different % minutesInMilli;

        long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

        System.out.printf(
            "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
            elapsedDays,
            elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);

    }
```

Comment: thanks but i am currently using only one activity so application gets stopped....I just want to calculate date difference in days

Comment: its giving me lots of error.Plz Sent tell me the code for selecting stardate from android calendar and end date as current date and find the date diifference

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Calendar` object then you can call `getTime()` method to convert (and format) into any String, e.g.:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMDD");
System.out.println("Formatted date " + dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));  
System.out.println("Date Object " + calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: thanks but i am taking input from calander and converting the string to yyyymmdd format so cant't solve